# Javascript Change Child node visibility to hidden in an ul

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have the following structure:

[image]

It looks like this:

[image]

I want to know how one can remove or hide "Test1" from there.

I tried using

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ms-core-suiteLinkList')[0].childNodes[0].style.visibility='hidden'
```

but it doesn't work because it says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined.

Using

```
 jQuery(".ms-core-suiteLink")[0].remove();
```

didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you try like this : `jQuery(".ms-core-suiteLink:first  > a").hide();` ?

Comment: That removes "MySite" as well

Comment: can you show your html as text ? or maybe try `jQuery(".ms-core-suiteLinkList:first .ms-core-suiteLink:first  > a").hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try either

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ms-core-suiteLink-a')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ms-core-suiteLink-a')[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
```

They should do the job.

Comment: The first one doesn't work. The second one works, but it removes "MySite" instead of Test

Comment: I don't really know why it didn't work for you. Could you share your codes please? It will be much easier